# No activity found to handle intent { act=android.intent.action.View }

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-video-player

I am launching Mx Player from my Application to play a video. But this error came when I am playing video.

[image]

> No activity found to handle intent { act=android.intent.action.View }

Here's my code. I have created a method for playing video when I directly put a link in play (`"http://www.example.com/dfgdf/grft.ts"`) it plays

```
    public void onClick(View v){
        int position = getLayoutPosition();
        final M3UItem imm = mItem.get(position);
        removeLastChar(imm.getItemUrl());

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Url: "+imm.getItemUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        playy(imm.getItemUrl());
    }

     public void playy(String uriil){
            try{
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(uriil); 
                intent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(videoUri, "application/x-mpegURL" );
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setPackage( "com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad" );
                mContext.startActivity( intent );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
//            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
//            mContext.startActivity(marketIntent);
        }
```

Comment: post your code what you have done .

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing your code and the complete stack trace associated with your crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can play your video in available video player in your Android Phone as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(uriil), "video/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "PLay video..."));
```

If you want to stream your video in **Mx Player** then follow this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944745/how-to-play-stream-video-using-intent-in-android)

Comment: now its just launching Mx player with this code but not streaming Url

Comment: oh you want to stream video.? For streaming video use **MediaPlayer** class

Comment: I just want to launch the link in Mx player with direct link its working but when getting link from array it says No activity found

Comment: @SajjadJaved may be problem with your url that you passing or video format not supported by the Mx player

Comment: no problem with url because url is playing in vlc & also in playy method like: playy("http://www.example.com/dfgdf/grft.ts") 
but not playing from array itemUrl (i'm reading a m3u file)